# Cloaks and parkour

Tags: internal-consistency, clothing

Cloaks keep you warm, protect you from the weather, act as camouflage if made right, and overall look cool.

Parkour is allows rapid movement in urban and sometimes/maybe natural environments, and also looks cool.

So why not combine the two? Increased coolness and practicality overall!  Right?  WRONG!

The lose piece of clothing on shoulders will get everywhere, catching everything, slowing you down and it just flipped over your head blinding you to the city guard running at you with his/her axe or to the mook with good aim. Overall, not a good idea. Yet in video games and even some books, this is a come depiction of rogues and assassins, of hunters and rangers; and for good reason, it looks cool.

So the question is, **can the concept of cloaks and parkour be combined realistically?**

Or more specifically, is there a cloak like piece of clothing that can be worn while parkouring your way to safety?

Specifications:

- A cloak like article of clothing is any piece of clothing draping over the body such as capes, ponchos, robes etc.
- Modifications to the garments are of course permitted.
- At least have one solution that isn't 'tie it down to the body', lets generate some ideas!

**Bonus Question**

Any one who can figure out how to put pockets on the inside gets brownie points;)

Comment: If you have enough time to prepare, you could roll up your cloak and fasten it to the back of your belt. Or you simply could let go of the cloak.

Comment: are combining it with gliding ok?

Comment: NopeNopeNope. Reference: https://youtu.be/M68ndaZSKa8?t=127  says it all.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to learn about this is [the Rule of Cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool):

> *The limit of the Willing Suspension of Disbelief for a given element is directly proportional to its awesomeness.*
>
> *Stated another way, all but the most pedantic of viewers* [that's us, WB users] *will forgive liberties with reality as long as the result is wicked sweet or awesome.*

Ezio Auditore and his enemies leap around in plate amour. You should really stop reality checking at that point if you wish to enjoy the series.

---

I don't do parkour, but some of my friends do. They either don't use loose clothing or, when they do, they use silver tape to adjust how loose it is. Fun fact: there are [zombie freerunners in Left 4 Dead, and if you pay close attention, you can see where the silver tape goes](https://left4dead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hunter).

---

Last but not least, [you could always ask the freerunners about it in a more specific SE site](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/27965).

---

> **Bonus Question**
>
> Any one who can figure out how to put pockets on the inside gets brownie points;)

[Cloaks with pockets have always been a thing.](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=cloak+with+pockets&iie=1)

Answer (score 2):

Parkour is a physically intensive activity.

While humans keep their core temperature constant, this is not true for their skin temperature: the more they exert, the warmer the skin becomes to dissipate the additional heat produced during the exercise.

Memory form alloy have the characteristic of returning to a certain shape when heated to a certain temperature.

Therefore threading some memory form alloy wire in the fabric making up the cloaks can do the trick of making the cloak fit snug when the bearer is exercising, because, you know, it's not like they can tell the guards chasing them "pretty please, let me fasten my cloak before I run away from you".

Answer (score 1):

Cloak is a cloak when not parkouring. Or not in specific parts of it.
As you notice the cloak add to wind resistance. So just grab the loose ends and glide to next rooftop. Or use vents for extra boost up.
Combine the cloak with a hoodie and you have face concealer and additional head cushion. Great for that "not so perfect" landings.

So how you cloak the cloak? Take the end and tuck it under your left armpit, across the chest to cover the liver and tuck behind your back. Or if it's long enough around your waist.

For the bonus point: the pocket is sew in the part of cloak that fall on your chest BUT you can also use it (in that form) like a shawl for carrying a baby. Great for blending in "ooooh look at me, I'm just a poor women who need to carry this baby in this wind slashing my face from which I'm hiding under my hood".